# Converting bytes to int

Tags: java, int, type-conversion, byte, mask

In my project I need to open the SEQ file, so I use FileInputStream, it requires to load data to byte array. But because of that each pixels get wrong value (cause they are Integers).

Below in my code you can see that i put pixels in 2d array and for that I count each value of pixel, in line:

```
 wart =(int) (buf[offset]) +(int)(buf[offset+1]) * 255;
```

I know that values because of byte input format are wrong (first two pixels aka double should be `152,109692453756 and 152,068644316116` but in my Java function they get  -`2474, -690`)

I tried using the mask:

```
wart =(int) (buf[offset]<< 8) & 0x0000ff00 +(int)(buf[offset+1])& 0x000000ff * 255  ;
```

it helps a little (values arent negative, but they are "shifted" too much (first two pixels `19456, 18944`)
I don't know how to solve this problem. I know that the mask should be different, but I don't know how to set it.

```
    public class Sekwencja2 {
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public double[] sekwencja2(String nazwa,int nr_klatki) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{            
                        InputStream is = null;
                        DataInputStream dis = null;                           
                        is = new FileInputStream(nazwa);
                        dis = new DataInputStream(is);                            
                        int length = dis.available();
                        byte[] buf = new byte[length];                           
                        dis.readFully(buf);                            
                        int l_klatek = ((length-158864)/158864)+1;                            
                        int width = 320;
                        int height = 240;
                        int C1=21764040;
                        double C2=3033.3;
                        double C3=134.06;
                        int z = 0;
                        double[] oneDArray = new double[width*height];                            
                        double [][] pixels = new double[width][height];                       

                        int offset =0;
                        char type;
                        String typeText;
                        type=(char)buf[0];
                        typeText =Character.toString(type);
                        switch (typeText) {
                            case "A":
                            if(nr_klatki == 1)
                            offset= 696;
                            else 
                            offset = 158136+(nr_klatki-1)*569+(nr_klatki-2)*(320*240*2+3839);
                            break;
                            case "F":
                            offset=(nr_klatki-1)*158864 + 1373;
                            break;
                            }                          

                        int wart = 0 ;                            
                        for(int x = 0; x<320; x++){
                         for (int y = 0; y<240;y++){
                             switch (typeText){
                                 case "A":
                                     if(nr_klatki==1)
                                         wart =(int) (buf[offset]) +(int)(buf[offset+1]) * 255;
                                     else
                                         wart = (int)(buf[offset]<< 8)& 0x0000ff00 +(int)(buf[offset+1])&0xff*255   ;
                                     break;
                                 case "F":
                                     wart = (buf[offset]<< 8)& 0x0000ff00  +(buf[offset+1])& 0x000000ff * 255  ;
                                     break;
                             }


                              System.out.print(", "+wart);

                               pixels[x][y]=wart;
                                 offset = offset+2;                                      
                         }
                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i < width; i ++)
                                {
                            System.arraycopy(pixels[i], 0, oneDArray, i * height, height);
                                }                       

        return oneDArray;
    }
}
```

I know it's a mess, a lot of things are commented :)

Comment: Please post a portion of the code that is reading the data and storing as well as provide an example of how the data looks like then we can try to help

Comment: Compulsory lecture; http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

255 is wrong

it's 256, you always have to multiply by a multiple of the base you are operating, 255 isn't a multiple of 2

analogy:

convert 111 from base 10 to base 10 in your way

1*99 + 1*9 + 1 = 109

so 109 != 111 which is wrong, likewise multiplying by 255 will alter any number you try to convert from binary to binary.

Answer (score 0):

Mask first, like this:

```
wart = (buf[offset] & 0xFF) | ((buf[offset+1] & 0xFF) << 8);
```

Comment: for first two 'wart' i got 63052, 64843

Comment: @KatarzynaKamińska So what? What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Something like 152, 152. I'm beginer so it's hard to understand it to me :(

Comment: @KatarzynaKamińska Here are some possibilities: 1) your offset is wrong, so you are using the wrong input, 2) the data is big-endian instead of little-endian, so the bytes are swapped, or 3) you need to scale the integer value by some normalizing factor (divide by some constant?)

Comment: What if data is big-endian instead of little-endian?

Comment: I checked, data is liitle-endian.

Comment: @KatarzynaKamińska What file format is this? Do your have a URL for a published specification? Your pixels are 16-bit values, and that's not a typical floating point representation. So, there's probably a function to convert to a floating point number that corresponds to a physical measurement. Like perhaps for medical imaging?

Comment: It's a seq file from flir camera used in thermography.